# Java: Naming convention for plural acronyms

Tags: java, naming-conventions, plural, acronym

I know there had already been similar discussions on such naming conventions. However, I'm having problem with plural acronyms.

```
public List<Disc> findAllDvds(DiscHolder holder) {}
public List<Disc> findAllDvd(DiscHolder holder) {}
```

Assuming that I have decided to use CamelCase for acronyms, which of the two is generally more acceptable?

### Edit

I am aware this will invite opinion-based answers, but sometimes when you are in doubt, you just need people to give advises and feedbacks.

To add on, the confusing part here is that `findAllDvds` can imply a new acronym `DVDS`, and it can be considered confusing.

Comment: You are returning with a collection. Is that not something obvious?

Comment: @StephenC Yes, I am aware I will hold the final say how things are going to be. But I just want to see if anyone has ever struggled through this and had came up with a choice, with a reason backing that decision. Using camelcase for acronym is also something I find more logical after reading many opinions from other SO questions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first (`findAllDvds`). The second (`findAllDvd`) is simply incorrect, "all" implies more than one, but "Dvd" is singular in English.

Re your edit:

> the confusing part here is that `findAllDvds` can imply a new acronym `DVDS`, and it can be considered confusing

Since the "all" implies multiple, the "s" on "Dvds" reads as a plural, not part of the acronym. If it really were DVDS, the name would be `findAllDvdss` or similar.

It's said that in computer science, there are three hard problems: Cache invalidation, and naming things. (Off-by-one errors are just common, not hard.)

Comment: This can be placed as a comment.

Comment: @KarelG: Answers don't go in comments, they go in answers. That's the SO model. It's not an unreasonable question, particularly for a non-native English speaker.

Comment: It does not fit the SO scope. But I won't do a cv or any downvotes because the OP is fairly new here. So I forgive it to him. You should know that.

Comment: I think I found something convincing here. That `dvdss` part sounds logical.

Comment: @PrzemysławMoskal: I think that would stray too far into opinion-land, and unfortunately, the JDK has used both. :-) (Personally, I prefer keeping the acronym in all caps perhaps with the exception of "Id" -- but I fear I may increasingly be in the minority on that.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Could you elaborate on more correct way: 1) `findAllDvds()` or 2) `findAllDVDs()` when singular is DVD? I found that acronyms are being written in both ways (all letters of acronym uppercase or only the first letter of acronym uppercase, the rest lowercase) and I'm not sure which one is considered as the better choice. Sorry for deleting comment (I thought that you edited answer after my comment and that's all), I have put it again here to let others know what I was asking for.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you for giving me these explanation. Personally I prefer DVDs over Dvds, too. It's a bit of surprise for me when you say it's not that common to uppercase whole acronym, seems like a more correct choice to me anyway. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is a really opinion based question and could be closed.

However, this should be the correct version:

```
public List<Disc> findAllDvds(DiscHolder holder) {}
```

Comment: This can be placed as a comment.

Comment: As @T.J. Crowder  mentioned: answers go in answers and comments in comments. No reason to downvote.

Comment: Did not have downvoted anything here. Feel free to check my badges. I never have done downvotes because I do not participate on such thing.